# Alternative to hashes to handle mixed types in Go

Tags: go

I'm doing a programming exercise to get familiar with Go. I'm currently writing a parser which parses a string into a command with arguments, e.g:

```
C w h           Should create a new canvas of width w and height h.
B x y c         Should fill the entire area connected to (x,y) with "colour" c.
Q               Should quit the program.
```

At first I started using hashes to hold the arguments e.g. `w` `h`. But this is inflexible and as you can see `c` is a colour which will be a string, while the other arguments are integers.

I've started like this:

```
package main

import (
    "errors"
    "strconv"
    "strings"
)

type command struct {
    id   string
    args map[string]int // Won't work because args can be of mixed types
}

func parseCommand(input string) (command, error) {
    if input == "" {
        return command{}, errors.New("No input")
    }

    commandParts := strings.Split(input, " ")

    switch commandParts[0] {
    case "C":
        if (len(commandParts)) != 3 {
            return command{}, errors.New("C (create) requires 2 arguments")
        }

        w, err := strconv.Atoi(commandParts[1])

        if err != nil {
            return command{}, errors.New("width must be an integer")
        }

        h, err := strconv.Atoi(commandParts[2])

        if err != nil {
            return command{}, errors.New("height must be an integer")
        }

        return command{
            id: "create",
            args: map[string]int{
                "w": w,
                "h": h,
            },
        }, nil
    case "B":
        if (len(commandParts)) != 4 {
            return command{}, errors.New("B (Bucket Fill) requires 3 arguments")
        }

        x, err := strconv.Atoi(commandParts[1])

        if err != nil {
            return command{}, errors.New("x must be an integer")
        }

        y, err := strconv.Atoi(commandParts[2])

        if err != nil {
            return command{}, errors.New("y must be an integer")
        }

        return command{
            id: "bucketFill",
            args: map[string]int{
                "x": x,
                "y": y,
                "c": commandParts[3], // This should be a string!
            },
        }, nil
    case "Q":
        return command{
            id: "quit",
        }, nil
    default:
        return command{}, errors.New("Command not supported")
    }
}
```

My question is how should I go about parsing an input string into a command, if the arguments I want to return are variable and have mixed types? Thanks.

P.S the commands are free typed in and modify a fake canvas in the terminal e.g:

```
enter command: C 20 4
----------------------
|                    |
|                    |
|                    |
|                    |
----------------------

// Didn't mention this one but it's a Line if you didn't guess
enter command: L 1 2 6 2
----------------------
|                    |
|xxxxxx              |
|                    |
|                    |
----------------------
```

Comment: Commands and arguments are always strings, hence are usually stored as such. Args are also often  order-dependent too, so I don't understand why you have a map. I would take a look at some cli frameworks and see how they handle things (it's usually with typed structs and flags, not with a single `map[string]T`)

Comment: Can you provide an example to your requirement?

Comment: Since I want to do arithmetic with the args I thought it was better to parse them upfront than do it every time I want to use the arg. In this exercise the user types those commands and I can't change it to flags as that is the requirement of the exercise.

Comment: @Dominic use golang command line flags or use intereface map[interface{}]T

Comment: @Metalhead1247 Thanks, since I can't use flags, I will try and do it with interfaces

Comment: I wouldn't use `interface{}` here. You need to think about what you want to do with these args. Make an interface for that, and conform the types that can be args to that interface. `interface{}` means "this can handle literally anything," which I don't believe is what you mean.

Comment: @RobNapier thanks, would you make an interface for each command?

Comment: Yes should use string as the key and value could be an interface

Comment: I need to look at this more; this approach doesn't look right.

Comment: @Dominic: If you want to parse the strings into other types ahead of time, then don't try to store those in a single map. Make a typed struct for your commands.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your approach to `command` isn't right. A `command` is something you can apply to a canvas. So we say so:

```
type canvas struct{ ... }

type command interface {
    apply(canvas *canvas)
}
```

Now there are several kinds of commands, each with its own arguments. When being used as a command, however, the caller shouldn't have to care what those arguments are.

```
type createCommand struct {
    width  int
    height int
}

func (c createCommand) apply(canvas *canvas) { ... }

type bucketFillCommand struct {
    x     int
    y     int
    color string
}

func (c bucketFillCommand) apply(canvas *canvas) { ... }

type quitCommand struct{}

func (c quitCommand) apply(canvas *canvas) { ... }
```

And then you can parse them (I'd probably pull all the parsing into functions, but this is fine).

```
func parseCommand(input string) (command, error) {
    if input == "" {
        return nil, errors.New("No input")
    }

    commandParts := strings.Split(input, " ")

    switch commandParts[0] {
    case "C":
        if (len(commandParts)) != 3 {
            return nil, errors.New("C (create) requires 2 arguments")
        }

        w, err := strconv.Atoi(commandParts[1])

        if err != nil {
            return nil, errors.New("width must be an integer")
        }

        h, err := strconv.Atoi(commandParts[2])

        if err != nil {
            return nil, errors.New("height must be an integer")
        }

        return createCommand{width: w, height: h}, nil
    case "B":
        if (len(commandParts)) != 4 {
            return nil, errors.New("B (Bucket Fill) requires 3 arguments")
        }

        x, err := strconv.Atoi(commandParts[1])

        if err != nil {
            return nil, errors.New("x must be an integer")
        }

        y, err := strconv.Atoi(commandParts[2])

        if err != nil {
            return nil, errors.New("y must be an integer")
        }

        return bucketFillCommand{x: x, y: y, color: commandParts[3]}, nil
    case "Q":
        return quitCommand{}, nil
    default:
        return nil, errors.New("Command not supported")
    }
}
```

Note that this return `nil` as the command when something fails, not `command{}`.

[Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/IkR47GDw2hQ)

Comment: Edit: Thanks! So the apply function which take a canvas struct, is used so that the various command structs fulfil the requirements of the command interface? Also if I want to check what the type of the returned command is, e.g. `quitCommand` how do I do that?

Comment: Yeah; the commands do whatever they're supposed to do to the canvas when you call `apply`. If you want to check for a specific command, that's just a two-value type assertion: https://tour.golang.org/methods/15

Comment: Is it possible to cast the command to a concrete type when `parseCommand` is called (so e.g. `command.width` can be ran), or do I have to do `concreteCommand, ok := command.(createCommand)` on a new line/new var?

Comment: Why do you want to access `command.width`? That doesn't seem right. You should do everything inside of `apply` (inside of `apply`, the type is the struct)

Comment: Ah yes that makes sense, this was just for a test